# jquery gantt plugin

Tags: php, jquery, json, gantt-chart

#### Situation

I'm using a jQuery gantt plugin from [here](http://taitems.github.com/jQuery.Gantt/) and integrating it with a PHP site I have. In terms of setting up the demo there are no problems; however when I try to feed the plugin some of my own data, it will throw up the following error:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

Now, I believe the above error is thrown due to the JSON object being unfamiliar to the plugin but, I just can't seem to package it correctly.

#### My JSON Data

[image: my json]

#### Demo JSON Data

[image: demo JSON]

Now, you can see other than a few differences, I am pretty close to the mark. Up next is the PHP code I use to generate this.

```
$aryOutput = array('source' => array());
if($aryTasks) {
    foreach($aryTasks as $aryTask) {
            
                            
        $aryOutput['source'][] =  array(
            'name' => $aryTask['task_stage'],
            'desc' => $aryTask['task_title'],
            'values' => array(array(
            'to' => '/Date('.time($aryTask['task_projected_end_timestamp']).')',
            'from' => '/Date('.time($aryTask['task_projected_start_timestamp']).')',
            'desc' => $aryTask['task_description'],
            'label' => $aryTask['task_description']
        ))
        );
    }            
}
$strJSON = json_encode($aryOutput, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Please can anyone offer some pearls of wisdom to resolve this matter. On a side note, from another question, I saw that the  class has to be gantt. This is not a problem, I can get the plugin working with a different data set.

Thank you

#### Edit

I noticed a small difference with the date field having an extra slash on it. After editing the code to add it, the error still occurs

Comment: The answer was so simple, I was being a moron and after staring at it for a few hours realised I was actually sending the source object and using it within source object...Thank you for having a look anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the complete delivered JSON is structure as needs be. In the above example, it is likely this is the output:

```
source : { source : { ... } }
```

This causes confusion with the plugin as it is unexpected data.